# Asking about a patent drafting advice

Tags: patent-applications

If am I going to use licensed technology to come up with a new patent, how should I mention it while drafting the application?

Comment: How do you mean you're using a licensed technology to come up with a patent? Do you mean you're using it in your implementation? Or does not invention rely on some other kind of technology?

Comment: I mean that in a certain part of the invention I am using a balloon which I have its license from its patent holder

Comment: my question is how should I mention this while drafting the patent application?

Answer (score 2):

You don't.

The purpose of a patent application is to describe your invention. Whether you have a licence to some technology used in the implementation of your invention is irrelevant, because that doesn't relate to the invention itself.

However, if your invention is predicated on another piece of technology (whether licensed or not), and no other more generic technology could replace it, then you would need to refer to that technology in the description. This could be by referring to a patent publication for that technology, or failing that, to the manufacturer and brand name.